# AWS Lambda (Java impl) not showing error message in the log

Tags: java, exception, aws-lambda

I tried throwing a RuntimeException from AWS lambda function implemented in Java.

```
class CustomException extends RuntimeException {
    public CustomException(String message, Exception cause){
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

I throw this exception in the lambda handler method as

```
throw new CustomException("Exception due to unavailable server", e);
```

assuming e is the exception thrown by the called service.

The exception log in cloudwatch shows the exception as `CustomException` and also shows the exception trace for `CustomException`.

I do not see the exception cause message and the actual exception that caused this exception in the cloud watch logs.

How can I see the message and the actual exception as well?

Thanks,